# Gradient direction not consistent (X vs Y) for an image

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, computer-vision, gradient

I understand that the gradient direction goes from a low to high value. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

I = np.zeros((3,4), dtype=np.float64)
I[:,0:3] = 1
Y,X = np.mgrid[0:3, 0:4]
Iy,Ix = np.gradient(I)

#plotting quiver plot 1
plt.quiver(X,Y, Ix,Iy,  color='r')
plt.imshow(I)
```

[image]

As you can see in plot 1 above, the direction is going from the 0 values (low) to the 1 values (high).

When I flip the matrix and follow the same procedure, the direction is reversed (high to low) as shown here:

```
I2 = np.zeros((3,4), dtype=np.float64)
I2[0:2,:] = 1
print(I2)
Iy2,Ix2 = np.gradient(I2)
plt.imshow(I2)
plt.quiver(X,Y, Ix2,Iy2,  color='r')
```

[image]

Shouldn't the arrows be pointing upwards instead of downwards? What am I missing?

Comment: My guess this is a Matplotlib issue. Images are usually displayed with the y-axis reversed, compared to plots. Just to check, make sure that the values in the `Iy` matrix are negative.

Comment: thanks @CrisLuengo, indeed the ```Iy``` term needs a negative sign to correct for it. ```plt.quiver(X,Y, Ix2,-Iy2,  color='r')```

Comment: Yes, you can correct it that way, but it **shouldn't** be necessary. My comment was wondering whether this is a bug in `np.gradient` or in Matplotlib.

Comment: I just relocated your code in MATLAB, and it works as expected there, the arrows are not reversed for Y.

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely a bug in `plt.quiver`. The `Iy2` values are correct. Doing `plt.quiver` by itself shows the arrows correctly (pointing down, which is the negative y direction by default). Adding the image inverts the axis, but doesn't invert the direction of the arrows.

Answer (score 1):

In order to correct for the y-axis being reversed, the quiver plot needs a negative in front of the `Iy` term.
`plt.quiver(X,Y, Ix2,-Iy2,  color='r')`